# A statement about the states in these United States

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A closer look at the states in the USA might tell you that:

> Indiana is in Alabama
>
> Alabama is in Georgia
>
> Georgia is in Minnesota

So what state is in Indiana?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I hear that:

> **NORTH DAKOTA**

is in Indiana.  Why?  Because in each case:

> the common **2-letter abbreviation of the state listed first** appears as a substring of the name of the **chemical element sharing its symbol with the state listed second**.

i.e.

> Indiana (**IN**) is in "Alabama" (AL), which is ALUM**IN**IUM;
>
>  Alabama (**AL**) is in "Georgia" (GA), which is G**AL**LIUM;
>
>  Georgia (**GA**) is in "Minnesota" (MN), which is MAN**GA**NESE.

So for Indiana:

> North Dakota (**ND**) is in "Indiana" (IN), which is I**ND**IUM.

Comment: By this rule, Indiana, Alabama and Georgia are also in themselves, but Minnesota is not.